# C# issue with class instantiation

Tags: class, visual-studio-2019, abstract

I'm running a C# project on VS2019 with the following code structure:

**In the Class1.cs file:**

```
public class Class1
{
    public class MyClass2 : Class2
    {
        ...
    }

    private void RunAlgorithm<T>() where T : Class2, new()
    {
        T argInstance = new T();
        ...
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAlgorithm<MyClass2>();
    }

}
```

**In the Class2.cs file:**

```
public class Class2
{
    public Class2() { }
    public string setParameters { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting the following error for the line `RunAlgorithm<MyClass2>();`

> 'Class1.MyClass2' must be a non-abstract type with a public
>   parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'Class1.RunAlgorithm()'

Comment: And what part of the error message are you struggling with understanding? It's pretty clear...

Comment: `private Class2() { }` - How do you expect to create an instance of `MyClass2`?

Comment: @David even if I change it to Public, the error persists.

Comment: @CaiusJard the type isn't abstract, and I have a parameterless constructor, so I've satisfied the conditions the error speaks of.. so I don't understand why it persists.

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky: I don't get that error when I compile this code.  But I *do* get an error where you try to invoke `RunAlgorithm<MyClass2>()` from a `static` method, as well as an error that `MyClass2` can't inherit from `Class2` because the constructor is inaccessible (since it's `private` in the code shown).  It sounds like the code you're showing and the code producing your error are two different things.

Comment: The posted code doesn't show that Class1.MyClass2 has a public parameterless constructor?

Comment: isn't `private Class2() { }` a public parameterless constructor? If I have that, why does the error say I don't?

Comment: No, it's a **private** parameterless constructor! :)

Comment: Do you have a `public MyClass2()` constructor? You don't need a public constructor on the base class, but on the concrete class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if I change it to Public, the error persists

Well, minimally, it'll have to be protected so that MyClass can access it..

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XFeEdQ

```
public class Class1
{
    class MyClass2 : Class2
    {
    }

    private void RunAlgorithm<T>() where T : Class2, new()
    {
        T argInstance = new T();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Class1().RunAlgorithm<MyClass2>();
    }

}


public class Class2
{
    protected Class2() { }
    public string setParameters { get; set; }
}
```

So your "Class1.MyClass2
must have a public parameterless constructor" message is saying that your MyClass needs a constructor. Mine above has such a constructor even though it's not in the code; in the absence of the developer providing a constructor the compiler provides one that does nothing other than call the base parameterless constructor...

...which leads me to the next point; your MyClass2 extends Class2, and hence Class2's constructor needs to be accessible to it. While Class2's constructor is private, MyClass2's constructor can't call it. Every constructor on c# has to either call another constructor or a base constructor. If you don't specify which, the compiler will insert a call to base() for you, which will fail if the base constructor is inaccessible

For this all to work out you need a public parameterless constructor in MyClass2:

- `public MyClass2():base(){}`
- or without the base(compiler will add the base call)
- or blank (compiler will add all of it)

and you need something that makes Class2's constructor accessible to MyClass2, ie declaring Class2's constructor as public or protected

Comment: But in the linked .NET fiddle, it compiles and runs (doesn't print anything). If you change the constructor to private (from protected) and run again it will give an error (about accessibility). If you provide a non public constructor in MyClass2 then you'll get the error you posted about

Comment: thanks, after adding a separate base constructor for MyClass2 (not just Class2), the error was solved! :)

Comment: Yes, it's important to remember that if you provide any kind of constructor then the compiler won't provide the default empty one